# Message context don't show in webview in android

Tags: android, webview, keyboard

I should show webpage in `webview`. Everything is ok, but in chat part of page I can not see what I type on keyboard when I start to type something to send.But after pushing back `button`, keyboard goes away, and I can see what I typed.I want to see what I type when keyboard is on.I searched all similar cases.But they are different from mine.
  [Hope this picture can describe my problem exactly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2htrz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add this option `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. Something like below:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
</application>
```

Adding this option will resize your `activity` when keyboard opens, So that nothing will be hidden behind the keyboard.